# ServiceStack JsonServiceClient missing

Tags: servicestack

I can't seem to access ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web in the new ServiceStack version 4.0.12.

Particularly I'm looking for JsonServiceClient that was present in older version.

Has it been removed? I can't seem to find any documentation online for v4.

Comment: Woops just found it under ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just [`ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) now. In the `ServiceStack.Client` assembly/[NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Client/).